# Why query not working in from my php

Tags: php, mysqli, dbforge

I have query, and i have database. When I query in dbforge(mysql) i got result. When from php, i got nothing. Can't understand why? If I write query simple like "select * from table where id = 1", its working. 
Below my code:

```
<?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "pass", "db");
            ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);     
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
            {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();

            }
            mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ");

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "Select distinct level_two FROM reportls._report_sales_report Where level_one = 'Музыка'");
            if($result == false)
            {
                die('INVALID QUERY: '.mysqli_error($conn));
                echo "error";
            }               
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
            {
            if(!empty($data[0]))
              $sendBack = $sendBack."<option value=\"$data[0]\">$data[0]</option>";
            }
            echo ($sendBack);
            $sendBack = '';
            mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

This code return nothing. But if I paste my query into my dbforge, it returns rows.
Could you help me, or write some hits? What i wrote not correct?

Comment: So, this query doesn't work? "Select distinct level_two FROM reportls._report_sales_report Where level_one = 'Музыка'"

Comment: Maybe, something is wrong with the enconding of the cyrillic word "Музыка"? Did you try a latin word?

Comment: @user4035, Yes. this query not working.

Comment: @user4035, But in dbforge it works fine.

Comment: "But in dbforge it worked fine" - I know. Can you write a latin word into the database, so we could see, whether the error is caused by the encoding or something else. And let me know.

Comment: @user4035, You are right, I test it with number and with latin, It's working. But I Write this line **mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ")**. Why isn't working?

Comment: Instead of this line `mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ")`, try: `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");`

Comment: @user4035, It's working. Thank you very much,much. I wish you good health.